# Как узнать: у Теофиля Готье новелла имеет двойное название или подзаголовок?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Форма: новелла

Оригинальное название: Arria Marcella

Перевод: Евгений Гунст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[АРРИЯ МАРЦЕЛЛА](https://profilib.net/chtenie/112681/teofil-gote-dva-aktera-na-odnu-rol-100.php)

[ВОСПОМИНАНИЕ О ПОМПЕЯХ](https://profilib.net/chtenie/112681/teofil-gote-dva-aktera-na-odnu-rol-100.php)

---

[АРРИЯ МАРЦЕЛЛА. ВОСПОМИНАНИЕ О ПОМПЕЯХ](http://librebook.me/two_actors_for_one_role/vol1/17)

---

[«Аррия Марселла» и другие новеллы](https://books.google.ru/books?id=P3jVDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT66&lpg=PT66&dq=%D0%90%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%85&source=bl&ots=4PzC2immTG&sig=kphggN5N4GF1HPMLsqbd7RPkHvM&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPxb6GwOXaAhXPbZoKHfOhAT4Q6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=%D0%90%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%85&f=false)

Перевод с французского Елены Айзенштейн

Автор: Теофиль Готье

---

Аррия Марцелла

Arria Marcella

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жанр

Новелла

Автор

Теофиль Готье

Язык оригинала

французский

Дата первой публикации

1852

---

[Аррия Марцелла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0) (лат. Arria Marcella) — фантастическая новелла Теофиля Готье, впервые напечатанная 1 марта 1852 в журнале Revue de Paris.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

И в конце концов, она Марселла или Марцелла? О_о

Comment: В любом случае фамилия от имени отскочила безо всякой причины.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Марселла и Марцелла - варианты произношения и написания, оба варианта корректны.

В словаре:

MARCELLA -  transcription, транскрипция: [ mɑ:ʹselə ]

•   n

•   Марселла, Марцелла ( женское имя )

•   Апресян Ю.Д., Медникова Э.М.. New big English-Russian dictionary Apresyan, Mednikova. 1994.

https://slovar-vocab.com/english-russian/new-big-dictionary/marcella-3992104.html 
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/eng_rus_apresyan/123925/Marcella

"Воспоминания о Помпеях" всё-таки, вероятно, подзаголовок, его пишут обычно в скобках:

> Отсылка к новелле Т. Готье «Аррия Марцелла (Воспоминания о Помпеях)»
>   педалирует значимый для Ходасевича мотив перехода мертвого в живое, и
>   живого – в мертвое: Готье рассказывает фантастическую историю о том,
>   как, глядя на кусок запекшейся лавы с вдавленным отпечатком, герой
>   влюбляется в мертвую помпейскую красавицу и тем самым воскрешает ее.

http://www.philology.nsc.ru/elib/data/Kulikova_Prostranstvo/Kulikova_Prostranstvo.pdf

> В новелле Т. Готье «Аррия Марцелла (Воспоминания о Помпеях)» главный
>   герой Октавиан влюбляется в очертания груди и бедра помпейской
>   красавицы, глядя на кусок запекшейся лавы с вдавленным отпечатком.
>   Любовь воскресила женщину, и Октавиан увидел предмет своих мечтаний
>   наяву.

http://portalus.ru/modules/culture/rus_readme.php?archive=&id=1257530017&start_from=&subaction=showfull&ucat=